# How get field value in form builder in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, builder

How to get field value in form builder in Symfony.
I have 2 Dropdowns in the form
I want to should the related option in Dropdown2 based on Dropdown1 in when the Page is Opening.

Here is My Form

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent;
use C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Entity\Students;
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
```

Field 1:

```
$builder->add('leadSource', 'entity', array( 
        'label' => 'How did you hear about C2?   Source ',

        'class' => 'C2EducateToolsBundle:LeadSources',
        'query_builder' => function($repo)  {
            return $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.sort_order', 'ASC');
        },
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => 'Select'

    ));
$leadSource = 1;
```

`$leadSource = 1;` - it works when I assign value statically, but I want to get the value of "leadSource" and assign it to `$leadSource`

I want to get the leadSource and pass it to leadSourceSub query

Field 2:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (DataEvent $event) { 
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $entity = $event->getData();
    $leadSource = $entity->getLeadSourceID();
    $form->add('leadSourceSub', 'C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Entity\Students', array(
            'label' => ' Source Detail ',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'C2EducateToolsBundle:LeadSourceSubs',
            'query_builder' => function($repo) use ($leadSource) {
                return $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->where('p.lead_source_id =:leadSource')
                        ->setParameter('leadSource', $leadSource)
                        ->orderBy('p.sort_order', 'ASC');
            },
            'property' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Select'
        ));
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get form data from `$builder`, because... it's a form **builder**, not a form. It doesn't contain any data yet.

To make this work you need to make use of `FormEvents`. In this case, you probably will need `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` event listener.

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) { 
        $form = $event->getForm();
        // in your case it's C2EducateToolsBundle:LeadSourceSubs
        $entity = $event->getData();
        $leadSource = $entity->getLeadSource();

        // adding this field again will override it.
        $form->add('leadSourceSub', 'entity', array(
                'label' => ' Source Detail ',
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'C2EducateToolsBundle:LeadSourceSubs',
                'query_builder' => function($repo) use ($leadSource) {
                    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')
                            ->where('p.lead_source_id =:leadSource')
                            ->setParameter('leadSource', $leadSource)
                            ->orderBy('p.sort_order', 'ASC');
                },
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_value' => 'Select'
            ));
        }
    });
```

Please note that this code is not tested and may need some validation like to check if `$entity` is what you expect it to be in any case.

Comment: Yes i Tried the Same from [Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms).i am getting an Error`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Form\Type\StudentsType::C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Form\Type\{closure}() must be an instance of C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Form\Type\FormEvent, instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c2Education\src\C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Form\Type\StudentsType.php line 121 `

Comment: You probably just copied the code and forgot to import namespace. `use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;`

Comment: It seems that you have pretty old Symfony, so probably need `use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent` instead of the one above and modify closure to expect `DateEvent` instead of `FormEvent`.

Comment: Yes. I used DataEvent, it working Fine, when I try to access my Entity it's not available. i updated my question in Field2 Can you Review it.

Comment: i am getting this issue `Fatal error: Call to a member function getLeadSourceID() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\c2Education\src\C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Form\Type\StudentsType.php on line 123` can you tell where are doing wrong.

Comment: You have a case when there's not underlying entity instance. That's why I previously said that this may require some validation. It it's null than you should return from event listener so the field would have  no options (or default if defined in `buildForm` method)